# Openshift issue with deploying using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, openshift

Need some help figuring out how to configure Jenkins on Openshift to deploy an app to Tomcat (JBoss EWS2.0).
The default setup using just rhc commands to instantiate a Jenkins gear and a JBoss EWS gear fails me.
I just changed the URL for the source control part in Jenkins, and it finds the source and the build works.
But it fails when trying to deploy with this message:

```
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/532351cee0b8cd0ba4000001/app-root/runtime/repo/pom.xml to /var/lib/openshift/532351cee0b8cd0ba4000001/.m2/repository/ca/architech/apl_web_sk_hb_mp/1.0/apl_web_sk_hb_mp-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.484s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 14 15:04:18 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "webapps/**". Configuration error?
ERROR: 'webapps/**' doesn't match anything, but '**' does. Perhaps that's what you mean?
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I noticed the build and deploy is done through shell with the gear command and all that stuff.
I would prefer to use Maven, since my project is maven-ized already, but then I cannot figure out how to configure the target URL for deployment in the pom.xml either.
So - either one option would do the trick for me!

Appreciate your help, attention and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, i managed to solve it by changing (as suggested) webapps/** by ** in the configurations at the bottom of this page :

`http://yourapp-domain.rhcloud.com/job/dev-build/configure`

I'm not really sure what it does though...

Comment: ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "deployments/**". Configuration error?  received the above in latest OpenShift . renamed to deployments as the directory name